# which dll file should have in bin for ajax control tool kit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

iam using ajax control tool kit for my application.. when i delploy my aplication to server it is throwing an error like below.. 
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

[image: these are the files added in bin and i think there are unwanted dll files please help me if i am right and let me know which has to be removed.]

this is the stack trace

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +70
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig..cctor() +68

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig' threw an exception.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager..ctor() +61
   ASP.employee_raiseticket_aspx.__BuildControlscriptmanager1() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\solventjobs.com\httpdocs\HelpDesk\Employee\RaiseTicket.aspx:207
   ASP.employee_raiseticket_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\solventjobs.com\httpdocs\HelpDesk\Employee\RaiseTicket.aspx:133
   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container) +10
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template) +88
   ASP.employee_employee_master.__BuildControlContentPlaceHolder1() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\solventjobs.com\httpdocs\HelpDesk\Employee\Employee.master:36
   ASP.employee_employee_master.__BuildControlform1() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\solventjobs.com\httpdocs\HelpDesk\Employee\Employee.master:14
   ASP.employee_employee_master.__BuildControlTree(employee_employee_master __ctrl) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\solventjobs.com\httpdocs\HelpDesk\Employee\Employee.master:1
   ASP.employee_employee_master.FrameworkInitialize() in App_Web_510p2djo.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +32
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +655
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +14
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +335
```

Comment: throwing error in this line <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
</ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: above files are in my bin which i think those are all not neccessary for ajay tool kit.. becoz of that i guess ajax not working.. if guys thinks thats true plz help me this.. thanks

Comment: what toolkit version you are using?

Comment: iam using ajax control tool kit  v4.0

Comment: did you remove your ajax toolkit and put new dll in your bin?

Comment: yea i already did like 3 to 4 times

Comment: and the replaced kit is the same from which you choose the ajax items. right? if not try the new kit in you local and don't forget to extract the ajax items and then run it on local

Comment: mean while please share your stack trace in the question